# How to send post data to a url and go to url with php?

Tags: php, curl

I want to send post data to url and go to url... I use `index.php` for login and send post data to `enter.php` but I don't know how to use post data in enter.php? 
I use `cURL`.

index.php :

```
<?
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c , CURLOPT_URL , 'http://localhost/enter.php');
curl_setopt($c , CURLOPT_POST , 1);
curl_setopt($c , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , 'name=Elmi&surname=Ehmedov');
curl_exec($c); curl_close($c);
?>
```

enter.php :

```
<?
$nm = $_POST['name'];
$snm = $_POST['surname'];
echo $nm , $snm;
?>
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: not go to `enter.php` open `enter.php` inside `index.php`.

Comment: The code you have works properly..what do you need ot happen next?

Comment: not change url. when I run index.php use enter.php but not change url.

Comment: You want to load index.php but post data to enter.php but not show the user you are in fact posting to enter.php?

Comment: @Dan I want to load enter.php and use post data from index.php. firstly I run index.php.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I am reading your question CORRECT then you need an AJAX call to complete your request to `enter.php`.

Since you are talking like you want to process your input-data which is in `enter.php` but user will see the form in `index.php` and when user submits the form it should post the data to `enter.php`.

Please use the following code snippet:

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$("#submit_form").submit(function()
{
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
        $.post("enter.php",{ name:$('#name').val(),surname:$('#surname').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data) //if correct login detail
          {
                $("#submit_response").html(data);
          }
       });

       alert("Problem in connecting your server.");

       return false;//not to post the  form physically
});
</script>

<!-- Show Message for AJAX response -->
<div id="submit_response"></div>

<form id="submit_form" action="javascript:login()" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value=""/>
<input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

enter.php

```
<?php

$nm = $_POST['name'];
$snm = $_POST['surname'];
echo $nm.", ".$snm;

?>
```

Comment: I want to send post data like 
`<form action = "enter.php" method = "post"></form>`
but your code not go to enter.php use enter.php inside index.php. not change url.

Comment: @Elmi Ehmedov please see the updated answer. I hope that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code of enter.php into index.php

You need to check if the user send a post request before checking/showing the "enter.php stuff"